# Android detects bluetooth gamepad as mouse

Tags: bluetooth, game-controllers, mouse

A couple of days ago I bought a bluetooth controller(Steelseries FREE Mobile Wireless Controller), but unfortunately my tablet detects it as mouse(I can move pointer with left analog etc.).

I have written a message to support, and they replied that they are sorry but there's nothing they can do...
So I decided to fix it myself. Some games that support keyboard controlling I can play with an app called Bluez IME. But all of the other - not :/

I started logcat in terminal and I've discovered that after I connect my gamepad, it loads hid-keyboard layout and says it's "keyboard mouse"

Below is photo of terminal with important part of logcat(Sorry it's a photo - I'm in a hurry)

[image: Terminal photo]

So my idea is to load my own prepared key layout file instead of hid-keyboard.kl, but I don't know how to achieve it.
Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:

dmupsys input also didn't give me a lot of information: device is called hid-keyboard(while on my phone it's full name of device), its Identifier is:
"bus=0x0019, vendor=0x0000, product=0x0000, version=0x0000" - that's why my configuration file didn't load, but I can't call it "vendor0000product0000.kl", because my tablet sees a couple ofother devices with this identifier :(

My guess would be that it's some system app that hijacks input from gamepad and gives me mouse pointer - it would be fine, but when I enter some game, it's still a cursor :<

Comment: look under /system/usr/keylayout ,do you see a file called hid-keyboard.kl ?

Comment: Yes, there is this file. I have already tried substituting it with my own, as no other device uses this file. Unfortunately, everything is the same way it was :/

I think it's some system app, that's emulating mouse instead of just letting it be a gamepad...